# N-bit-String contains of zeros and one “1” bit

Tags: logic

Design a circuit contains of only basic logical gates (2 bit gates such as AND, OR, XOR, NAND and NOT gate) and constants:

Input: n bit string A[0:n-1]

Output: two bits:

Y=1 only if all bits are 0

Z=1 only if the string consists of one 1 and n-1 zeros.

**No recursion allowed**

My attempt:

First, put N not gates for all the bits. than, put N "and trees" (gets n bits and returns its x and y and z etc.).
Every And tree gets one bit as original and n-1 bits after a not gate.
At last, "or tree" which its input is the result of all "And-trees" and its output is Z. For y, one "And-tree" which gets all the bits after a not gate and its output is y.

I think there is a more efficient solution which uses less gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Let me show a procedure that can lead to a well organized structure for $n=4$ first.

**As far as $Y$**

The canonical form of the output is

$$Y=\overline I_1 \overline I_2 \overline I_3 \overline I_4.$$
This expression cannot be simplified. The physical realization is and AND tree of the NOT's of the inputs.

**As far as $Z$**

The canonical form is

$$Z=I_1\overline I_2 \overline I_3\overline I_4+\overline I_1 I_2 \overline I_3\overline I_4+\overline I_1 \overline I_2  I_3\overline I_4+\overline I_1 \overline I_2  \overline I_3 I_4$$

For the first and the second terms we can write

$$I_1\overline I_2 \overline I_3\overline I_4+\overline I_1 I_2 \overline I_3\overline I_4=(I_1\overline I_2+\overline I_1 I_2)\overline I_3\overline I_4.$$

For the first and the third terms we can write

$$I_1\overline I_2 \overline I_3\overline I_4+\overline I_1 \overline I_2  I_3\overline I_4=(I_1\overline I_3+\overline I_1I_3)\overline I_2\overline I_4.$$

For the first and the fourth term we have

$$I_1\overline I_2 \overline I_3\overline I_4+\overline I_1 \overline I_2  \overline I_3 I_4=(I_1\overline I_4+\overline I_1I_4)\overline I_2\overline I_3.$$

Hence

$$Z=(I_1\overline I_2+\overline I_1 I_2)\overline I_3\overline I_4+(I_1\overline I_3+\overline I_1I_3)\overline I_2\overline I_4+(I_1\overline I_4+\overline I_1I_4)\overline I_2\overline I_3.$$

This is already the simplest form which can be realized with AND, NOT, and OR gates. That is, the case could be closed for $n=4$. For the sake of generality, let' take one step forward.

Regarding the first two terms we have

$$(I_1\overline I_2+\overline I_1 I_2)\overline I_3\overline I_4+(I_1\overline I_3+\overline I_1I_3)\overline I_2\overline I_4=[(I_1\overline I_2+\overline I_1 I_2)\overline I_3+(I_1\overline I_3+\overline I_1I_3)\overline I_2]\overline I_4.$$

The basic element of the circuitry is the following unit:

[image]

---

If we had $n$ inputs then the procedure shown above would have led to a sum of terms of the following form
$$(I_1\overline I_k+\overline I_1 I_k)\overline I_2,\overline I_3,\cdots,\overline I_{k-1},\overline I_{k+1}\cdots\overline I_n$$

where $k=2,3,\cdots,n$

Considering two such terms, say, with $k=2$ and $k=3$

$$(I_1\overline I_2+\overline I_1 I_2)\overline I_3\overline I_4\cdots\overline I_n+(I_1\overline I_3+\overline I_1 I_3)\overline I_2\overline I_4\cdots\overline I_n=$$
$$=[(I_1\overline I_2+\overline I_1 I_2)\overline I_3+(I_1\overline I_3+\overline I_1 I_3)\overline I_2]\overline I_4\cdots\overline I_n.$$

By this method you can always achieve that only pairs of inputs and / or partial results will have to be combined.

The basic element of the circuitry is still the unit depicted above.

Comment: thanks, taking your solution and using XOR gates for each expression in a brackets would give the least gates solution.